# Error assigning to a submatrix diagonal with drop=FALSE

Tags: r

When calling `diag<-`, you can pass a slice of the matrix and get the proper behavior, as long as you don't specify `drop=FALSE`.

```
> X <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
> diag(X[-1,]) <- c(1,2)
> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    2    0
```

Specifying `drop=false` is a different story

```
> diag(X[-1,,drop=FALSE]) <- c(3,4)
Error in diag(X[-1, , drop = FALSE]) <- c(3, 4) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
```

Note:

```
> identical(X[-1,], X[-1,,drop=FALSE])
[1] TRUE
```

As noted by MrFlick, assignment to a slice when the `drop` argument results in the same error:

```
X[1,] <- 1
X[1,,drop=TRUE] <- 2
Error in X[1, , drop = TRUE] <- 2 : incorrect number of subscripts
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because your LHS then becomes / remains a matrix?

Comment: actually, the error seems to appear with `diag(X[-1,,drop=TRUE]) <- c(3,4)`. so it's not unique to FALSE. In fact, I don't think it's unique to diag. For example `X[,,drop=TRUE] <- 1:3` appears to throw the error as well

Answer (score 3):

According to the `?"[<-"` help page, `drop=` "only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement" Thus you are not allowed to use a `<-` with `drop` which is basically what `diag()` is doing. As in my comment above, something like `X[,,drop=TRUE] <- 1:9` is not allowed either. Too bad the error message isn't a bit more specific.

Comment: It is logical to assume that `diag<-` internally calls the same function as `[<-`.

Comment: Yes, if you type `\`diag<-\`` you can see the code. The reassignment happens with a final `x[cbind(i, i)] <- value`

Comment: What's unusual is that if you do `debug('diag<-')` the assignment works just fine before failing when trying to return `x`

Comment: That's a good point @thelatemail. You're right that all the code in `debug<-` will work, it must be the mechanism that swaps out the returned value for the original one in the assignment that gets confused. That must lie in the Primitive code I guess.